# protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter creates report but with result as '0' and no screenshots

Tags: protractor

I have been trying to get the html report and screenshots of my execution result using "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter" but HTML report is created with content like

Report

Summary

Total specs tested: 0

Total failed: 0

And no screenshots is saved at the location.

### HTML report screenshot here

[image: HTML report screenshot here]

My config file is as below

```
    var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
    var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
    dest: 'target/screenshots',
    filename: 'my-report.html'
    });
    exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['Login_spec3.js'],
    allScriptsTimeout: 180000,
    getPageTimeout: 180000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
     defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
    },

   // Setup the report before any tests start
   beforeLaunch: function() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve){
     reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
   });
   },

   // Assign the test reporter to each running instance
   onPrepare: function() {
     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
     afterAll(function(done) {
       process.nextTick(done);
     })
   },
    // Close the report after all tests finish
     afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve){
     reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
     });
   },
   onPrepare: function() {
     var width = 1300;
     var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width,height);
    }
   };
```

Other details are as below:
protractor@3.2.2,
nodeVersion: 4.2.4,
npmVersion: 2.14.12,
jasmine: 2.4.1,
selenium-webdriver: 2.52.0

Can anybody suggest me any solution?

Comment: it is not finding your specs, check the path of your specs!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by 'check the path of spec'?. Can you please tell me what should be the folder structure?

Comment: My folder structure for conf and spec file is: User/My_folder/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation, inside FFAutomation i have all my spec files and conf file. Folder structure for "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter" is: User/My_folder/node_modules. And my target folder is getting created inside FFAutomation folder. Do I need to change anything? please suggest.

Comment: so your spec files are in the same folder where your config file is?

Comment: try changing your spec config to >  specs: ['./Login_spec3.js']

Comment: yes, conf and spec files are in same folder.

Comment: i think it should work now

Comment: No luck, still getting the same result as '0' even when changed to specs: ['./Login_spec3.js'],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sonal: Got the issue, you are using 2 onPrepare functions which is conflicting, use only one, so the modified working config will be:

```
  var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
  var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots'
, filename: 'my-report.html'
});
exports.config = {

directConnect: true, //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
}
, framework: 'jasmine'
, specs: ['spec.js']
, allScriptsTimeout: 180000
, getPageTimeout: 180000
, jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
},

// Setup the report before any tests start
beforeLaunch: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
},

// Close the report after all tests finish
afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
}
, onPrepare: function () {
    var width = 1300;
    var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    afterAll(function (done) {
        process.nextTick(done);
    })
}
};
```

I tested it in my system and it is working perfectly ;)